# Getting notified of password prompt C# System.Diagnostic.Process

Tags: c#, command-line, process

I've been trying to implement a C# wrapper around the git executable using System.Diagnostic.Process and have hit a bit of a wall. What I'd like to do is when interacting with remote repositories, to pop up a password prompt in my app whenever git prompts for a username and password. This would allow the user to make use of all the built in git password credential storing tools automatically, and still have the option of inputting their credentials in the app when those are not in use.

What I've tried is the following code.

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c git fetch";

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("OUTPUT DATA: " + e.Data);
    };
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("ERROR DATA: " + e.Data);
    };

    process.Start();

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();
```

I see the command window pop up with "Password for: http://www.gitrepo.com" but I don't see this output in either my OutputDataReceived or ErrorDataReceived callbacks for reading by my app. Ideally I'd like to trigger an event when these prompts arise and show a nice username/password dialog box for the user.

I dug through the git code a bit and found that these password prompts are output to and read from /dev/tty. Now I'm not super familiar with how input/output streams and TTYs work. I'm wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for how I might be able to detect when this prompt pops up and allow the user to pass in the

Comment: Why are you calling `cmd.exe` with the arguments `/c git fetch` and not just calling `git.exe` with the arguments `fetch`?

Comment: Also possibly helpful related [question from Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/199507/how-do-i-ensure-git-doesnt-ask-me-for-my-github-username-and-password)

Comment: Sorry, that was just something I was trying. I originally had it set to just call "git" and have reverted it back to that. I get the same behavior either way though. Thanks for the link, but that's not really what I'm looking for. I want git to ask me for a username. I just want the user to have the ability to specify that username if and only if git prompts them for it.

Comment: I'm fully aware that what I want to do may not even be possible. In which case I'll investigate building in my own password caching mechanism in my app. I figure if git already has a very robust password caching API built into it why re-invent that? I should let the users make full use of that if they want and only allow them to input a password if git can't find one from their own credentials API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha. I found the answer. I can make a small little GUI application that git will prompt me with whenever it needs a password by setting "git config core.askpass

I tested with the following askpass script and it works just as needed.

http://code.metager.de/source/xref/git/git-gui/git-gui--askpass